# Integer points of one Mordell equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations, magma

How can I determine all integer points of the following equation

$$y^2=x^3+10546$$

I tried [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) with

```
IntegralPoints(EllipticCurve([0,10546]));
```

but got the answer that it "could not determine the Mordell-Weil group." What are my options here?

Comment: I have edited the tags a bit - it is recommended to use at least one [top level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1457/why-are-mo-tags-formatted-as-they-are) on [mathoverflow.se]. I wasn't entirely sure whether or not to include the tag ([tag:magma]) - feel free to remove it if you think it does not fit.

Comment: There are some nice papers containing data related to the question: Gebel, Pethő and Zimmer: On Mordell’s equation, Compos. Math. 110, No. 3, 335-367 (1998) and Bennett and Ghadermarzi: Mordell’s equation: a classical approach,
LMS J. Comput. Math. 18, 633-646 (2015) (here the technique is applied in case of $|k|<10^7$ to the equation $y^2=x^3+k.$)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This curve has rank 0 over $\mathbb{Q}$. The 2-descent fails to determine this, because the $2$-torsion subgroup of the Tate-Shafarevich group is non-trivial. Instead, one can compute the $L$-value. One can prove that $L(E,1) = 16 \Omega_{+}$. By Kolyvagin, this implies that the rank is $0$.

Now one just needs to compute the torsion order and since there are no non-trivial torsion points. One gets $E(\mathbb{Q})=\{O\}$ and hence there are no integral points either.

Comment: Nice! Can you please point to the origin of $L(E,1)$.

Comment: sage, magma, pari,... they can all compute $L$-function with sufficient precision to convince you that $L(E,1)\neq 0$. For the precise proven value of 16 I used my own code.